# Spring Security Expression: "authenticated" vs. "isAuthenticated()"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

According to the [Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-common-built-in), the expression to check whether a user is authenticated is `isAuthenticated()`. So we would do `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`, for example.

However, according to the [official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/5.5.x/reactive/webflux/java/method/src/main/java/example/MessageService.java) and confirmed by my own testing, `@PreAuthorize("authenticated")` also works.

Is it a Spring Security feature or perhaps simply a Java feature (e.g. `authenticated` is the field that backs the getter `isAuthenticated()` somewhere) that makes `authenticated` work as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `@PreAuthorize` is an SpEL , which according from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-common-built-in) , it will evaluate against the root object `SecurityExpressionRoot`.

`isAuthenticated()` is the syntax to invoke `isAuthenticated()` on the `SecurityExpressionRoot` instance (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-methods)) .

While `authenticated` is the syntax to access the properties of the `SecurityExpressionRoot` instance (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-properties-arrays)). It will try to invoke the following **public** property or methods to evaluate the value :

- `authenticated` property
- `getAuthenticated()`
- `isAuthenticated()` (Only if the evaluated value is boolean)
- `authenticated()`

You could find such logic in the codes at [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/22f0f9f3df2cd2bea024f557e834043bda02f80e/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/support/ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java#L392).

Comment: I see. A deviation from the question and out of curiosity, where is SpEL used besides in Spring Security annotations?

Comment: You can search the codebase to see which part of codes uses the class `EvaluationContext` . For example, it is used a lot in the [spring-intergration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html) . Also used in the `@Cacheable` [feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-spel-context) etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the source code in `org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`:

```java
private boolean isAuthenticated() {
    return getUserPrincipal() != null;
}
```

then look into `getUserPrincipal()`:

```java
@Override
public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
    Authentication auth = getAuthentication();
    if ((auth == null) || (auth.getPrincipal() == null)) {
        return null;
    }
    return auth;
}
```

then `getAuthentication()`. this is key point:

```java
private Authentication getAuthentication() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();//!!!
    return (!this.trustResolver.isAnonymous(auth)) ? auth : null;
}
```

as it shows, `authentication` object is managed by `SecurityContextHolder`.

as for `authenticated`, I think it might be a singleton Java bean in spring bean container. it has the same value as:

```java
authentication.isAuthenticated();
```

in `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication`

Comment: good try but i am afraid it does not work like this. please see my answer